# How to have different form for creating and editing a model

Tags: python, django

I'm using django and I have a model that contain a password field. On the creation of a new model I want to show two password field (one for typing and the other for validation) but when editing a model I want to show only one read only field that contains the hash code of the password.

What I want to do is exactly what has been done for the `User` model. I have looked in the code but I haven't found where are the `ModelForm` of `User`.

So where to look in django code or how to know if I'm on creation or editing mode.

Here's what I'm done :

**admin.py**

```
class myModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = myModelForm

admin.site.register(myModel, myModelAdmin)
```

**form.py**

```
class myModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        # I commented this otherwise I get password field on editing mode
        """widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
    }"""
```

**models.py**

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_password(str(self.password))
        super(myModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = hashlib.sha512(raw_password).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by overriding the `get_form` method of the ModelAdmin class.

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    defaults = {}
    if obj is None:
        return myModelCreationForm
    defaults.update(kwargs)
    return super(myModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **defaults)
```

I found the answer [here](http://reliablybroken.com/b/2009/01/using-separate-forms-for-adding-and-changing-in-djangos-admin/). We can  look [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py) to django solution for User Model.